# How to open webview not by chrome browser but by ionic

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

My code is as below.
I want to open google.com not on Chrome or basic browser but open on Ionic native I changed the second parameter to **_self, _blank, _system** 
and Ionic Cordova ran the Android to check on my device,
but whenever I came to the place, it ask me to open on Chrome or other browser and if I click one browser, it open it on that browser.

How can I open web site on Ionic?

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public navParams : NavParams,
  public modalCtrl:ModalController,private iab:InAppBrowser
   public fb:FirebaseService) {
    const options:InAppBrowserOptions={
      location:'no',
      fullscreen:'yes'
    }
    const browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com','_system',options);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already mentionend, the second parameter should be changed to *_blank* to open the link inside ionic:

```
  openWithInAppBrowser(): void {
    const browser = this.iab.create('https://google.com', '_blank');
  }
```

If that is not going to work, please verify if you installed the plugin correctly:

- ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
- npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser.

If you need more help, please post the whole code and your ionic environment info (ionic info).